# Binding SelectedItem in nested ListBox using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to use Caliburn.Micro to bind a view model of a nested `ListBox` but I'm stuck.
I have a list workspace that is divided in two sections a list of groups containtaining items in a different part of that workspace I want to show the details of either a group or an item in a group depending on what is the `SelectedItem`. I'm new to Caliburn.Micro and looked at the documentation and samples but don't know how to connect the dots. Specifically I'm trying to model this after the Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens sample. The code I have so far:

The ViewModel:

```
public class AnalyzerGroupWorkspaceViewModel : Conductor<AnalyzerGroupWorkspaceViewModel>, IWorkspace
{
    private Selected selected = Selected.AnalyzerGroup;

    private const string name = "Analyzers";

    public AnalyzerGroupWorkspaceViewModel(
        IMappingEngine fromMapper,
        IRepository<Model.AnalyzerGroup> analyzerGroups)
    {
        AnalyzerGroups = new ObservableCollection<IAnalyzerGroupViewModel>(analyzerGroups.GetAll().Select(fromMapper.Map<Model.AnalyzerGroup,AnalyzerGroupViewModel>));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IAnalyzerGroupViewModel> AnalyzerGroups { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get { return name; } }

    public Selected Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            if (value == selected) return;
            selected = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Selected);
        }
    }

    private IConductor Conductor { get { return (IConductor) Parent; } }

    public void Show()
    {
        var haveActive = Parent as IHaveActiveItem;
        if (haveActive != null && haveActive.ActiveItem == this)
        {
            DisplayName = name;
            Selected = Selected.AnalyzerGroup;
        }
        else
        {
            Conductor.ActivateItem(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Philips.HHDx.SSW.AnalyzerGroup.AnalyzerGroupWorkspaceView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <DockPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="AnalyzerGroups" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ListBox x:Name="AnalyzerGroups">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <ListBox x:Name="Analyzers">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id }"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Details">
        <ContentControl cal:View.Context="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        cal:View.Model="{Binding}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </GroupBox>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Next to that I have two `UserControl`s that display the detailsof a group or item.
My specific question is how can I use the `SelectedItem` property of the two `ListBoxes` to modify the `Selected` property to switch between displaying the `AnalyzerGroup` details and the `Analyzer` details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to the above described problem the solution consists of four parts:

- Add a `IsSelected` property (that notifies changes) to both 'child' ViewModels
- Bind the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to the `IsSelected` property of the respective ViewModels
- Attach a Caliburn.Micro `Message` to the 'outer' `ListBox` and use the `$eventArgs` argument
- In the ViewModel bound to the entire UserControl implement the method corresponding to the `Message` and use the `AddedItems` property of the `eventArgs` to set the `SelectedViewModel` property setting the `IsSelected` property of the previous `SelectedViewModel` to `false`

The code then becomes:

The ViewModel:

```
public class AnalyzerGroupWorkspaceViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IAnalyzerGroupWorkspaceViewModel
{
    private IAnalyzerViewModel selectedViewModel;

    private const string WorkspaceName = "Analyzers";

    public AnalyzerGroupWorkspaceViewModel(
        IMappingEngine fromMapper,
        IRepository<Model.AnalyzerGroup> analyzerGroups)
    {
        AnalyzerGroups = new ObservableCollection<IAnalyzerGroupViewModel>(
            analyzerGroups.GetAll().Select(
                fromMapper.Map<Model.AnalyzerGroup, AnalyzerGroupViewModel>));
    }

    public void SelectionChanged(object eventArgs)
    {
        var typedEventArgs = eventArgs as SelectionChangedEventArgs;
        if (typedEventArgs != null)
        {
            if (typedEventArgs.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                var item = typedEventArgs.AddedItems[0];
                var itemAsGroup = item as IAnalyzerViewModel;
                if (itemAsGroup != null)
                {
                    SelectedViewModel = itemAsGroup;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IAnalyzerGroupViewModel> AnalyzerGroups { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get { return WorkspaceName; } }

    public IAnalyzerViewModel SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, selectedViewModel))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (SelectedViewModel != null)
            {
                SelectedViewModel.IsSelected = false;
            }
            selectedViewModel = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Philips.HHDx.SSW.AnalyzerGroup.AnalyzerGroupWorkspaceView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <DockPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="AnalyzerGroups" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ListBox SelectionMode="Single"
                     x:Name="AnalyzerGroups"
                     cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action SelectionChanged($eventArgs)]">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Analyzers}" >
                                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name }" Margin="10" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Border>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Details">
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" />
        </GroupBox>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Pretty obvious that my answer guided you  on what you should do. You're welcome. And my suggestion is better than using some of the attached properties of Caliburn Micro like View.Model. Meh.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific question is yes, you can.

On the ViewModel of your UserControl. You create a property that is a ViewModel of either of the two details.

```
public interface IAnalyzerViewModel
{

}
```

Next, create two ViewModels for the Views of your `Analyzer` and `AnalyzerGroup` views.

```
public class AnalyzerGroupViewModel : IAnalyzerViewModel 
{

}

public class AnalyzerViewModel : IAnalyzerViewModel
{

}
```

Next, create a property in your UserControl's ViewModel that implements `INPC` or `PropertyChangedBase` of `Caliburn Micro`.

```
public class MainViewModel :
{
  private IAnalyzerViewModel _analyzerViewModel;
  public IAnalyzerViewModel SelectedViewModel { get { return _analyzerViewModel; } set { _analyzerViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedViewModel); }

  //Hook up the selected item changed event of your listbox and set the appropriate ViewModel to show, so if you either want to show the AnalyzerGroup or AnalyzerView.
}
```

And lastly, just update your `MainView` to

```
<ContentControl x:Name="SelectedViewModel"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

`Caliburn` will hook up the appropriate bindings and stuff and will pull the View for the associated ViewModel, and also the Name convention part will automatically map it to any public property of its datacontext as long as the names match.